# SQL database help needed via html form and php scripts

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html, phpmyadmin

```
<?php

include ("account.php") ;

( $dbh = mysql_connect ( $hostname, $username, $password ) )
        or    die ( "Unable to connect to MySQL database" );
print "Connected to MySQL<br>";

mysql_select_db($project);

$number =   NULL ;
$username   =   $_POST["username"];
$priority   =   $_POST["priority"];
$category = $_POST["category"];
$incident_description = $_POST["incident_description"];


$sql  =   "insert into incident values ( NULL,       '$username','$priority','$category','$incident_description',curdate(),curtime() )" ;

mysql_query ( $sql )    or   print ( mysql_error ( ) );

$credentials = "select * from Credentials where ("username" = '$username' ,"password" =  '$password' , "email_address" = 'email_address')" ;

print $credentials;

$result = mysql_query ($credentials) or print (mysql_error ( ) );

$howManyRows = mysql_num_rows ( $result);

//if $howManyRows is positive continue process to update database with sql,if not,die.
?>
```

There is an html code for a form on another file hence the $_POST, but I don't think it s necessary to show it here since I need the right syntaxes on this php file.

With the part from the `$credentials` I need help with how to  compare the values in the html form `(username,password,email_address)` with values in the table `"Credentials"` from the database?I need to do this in order to authorize the values to carry on the process.
The syntax I got there isn't right at the moment because it doesn't execute it properly. I just don't know how to compare the two. 
This whole thing works up until the `mysql_query ( $sql )    or   print ( mysql_error ( ) )` line.

Suggestions would be nice.I apologize for the long question!

PS: columns for the Credentials table are `username,password,email_address` as well!

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is here

```
$credentials = "select * from Credentials where ("username" = '$username' ,"password" =  '$password' , "email_address" = 'email_address')" ;
```

change to

```
$credentials = "select * from Credentials where `username` = '$username' and `password` =  '$password' and  `email_address` = 'email_address'" ;
```

The problem is in query, when you want to check multiple values use `AND` in `WHERE` clause.

Comment: It is inserting values into the database no problem,but how do I know if it actually is authorized?

Comment: all it shows is that line select * from credentials ,and it puts the actualy values of $username ,password and email. And at the end it says Operant should contain 1 column but the data has gotten in the database

Comment: it says Operand should contain 1 columns

Comment: is that the answer?resource id# 4?what is that?

Comment: this is returning a result when some query is executed without error.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know but shouldn't u use the following...

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO incident (fieldname, fieldname) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape($_POST['fieldname'])."', '".mysql_real_escape($_POST['fieldname'])."')";
```

To insert anything into mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Try

> $password = mysql_real_escape($_POST['password']); //to avoid SQL injunction
> $username = mysql_real_escape($_POST['username']);
>
> $credentials = "select * from Credentials where `username` = '$username' AND `password` =  '$password' AND `email_address` = 'email_address'" ;

Comment: I think it works at this step, because the values get inputted into the database and it doesnt say there's a syntax error,but says the operand should contain 1 column. 

I m supposed to authorize the credentials table with values the user inputs from the html form. How do I do this ?Thats the last step I wrote with the $howManyrows part...Im confused as to if I should use if or while loop

Comment: check 'if($howManyrows==1){ //your code}' all the users have unique password and username. so $howManyrows should have the value 1

Comment: wouldn't it be if($howManyrows > 0) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your credential query as below

```
$credentials = "select * from Credentials where username = '$username' AND password = '$password' AND email_address = 'email_address'" ;
```

BUT for better performance & to prevent your code for mysql injection you have to do following things

1) Use Mysqli instead of mysql functions. here is good lib for mysqli as wrapper 
https://github.com/nWidart/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

2) Always keep your database connection string to separate file and at safe place. then, include your connection file into your require project file.

3) Always validate value of your variables & use mysql_real_escape before using directly into query.